# How can I ensure a URL points to safe, non-adult, non-spam content when allowing people to post content to my website?

Tags: php, validation

I am working on a PHP site that allows users to post a listing for their business related to the sites theme. This includes a single link URL, some text, and an optional URL for an image file.

Example:

```
<img src="http://www.somesite.com" width="40" />
<a href="http://www.abcbusiness.com" target="new">ABC Business</a>
<p>
Some text about how great abc business is...
</p>
```

The HTML in the text is filtered using the class from [htmlpurifier.org](http://htmlpurifier.org) and the content is checked for bad words, so I feel pretty good about that part.

The image file URL is always placed inside a `<img src="" />` tag with a fixed width and validated to be an actual HTTP URL, so that should be Ok.

The dangerous part is the link.

**Question**:
How can I be sure that the link does not point to some SPAM, unsafe, or porn site (using code)?

I can check headers for 404, etc... but is there a quick and easy way to validate a sites content from a link.

EDIT:

I am using a CAPTCHA and do require registration before posting is allowed.

Comment: That's a tricky one - I don't think there's an easy way :(

Comment: Tragically I suspect "moderation" is the only safe way to be sure.

Comment: Require users to register, throw captchas at them. Oh, and moderate.

Comment: Moderate the images. Also, cache them locally so they can't simply change the image to spam after it's been approved.

Comment: do any of the filtering companies provide an api that will allow you to submit a URL and return an 'appropriateness' flag?

Comment: You can use this API https://rapidapi.com/logicione/api/porn-or-nsfw-content-detection , it checks for any porn link and text. URL-Expander API https://rapidapi.com/logicione/api/url-expander1 checks if link is dead or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there a quick and easy way to validate a sites content from a link.

No. There is no global white/blacklist of URLs which you can use to somehow filter out "bad" sites, especially since your definition of a "bad" site is so unspecific.

Even if you could look at a URL and tell whether the page it points to has bad content, it's trivially easy to disguise a URL these days.

If you really need to prevent this, you should moderate your content. Any automated solution is going to be imperfect and you're going to wind up manually moderating anyways.

Comment: "it's trivially easy to disguise a URL" I'd go so far as to say "it has always been..." rather than "...these days."  Otherwise +1 !

Comment: @Stephen I said "these days" specifically because of the proliferation of URL shortening services, furiously competing to be the go-to URL obfuscator. There have never been quite so many options available to easily hide the exact page a link leads to.

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought. ;) I was just trying to emphasize the triviality.

Answer (score 9):

Its going to be very hard to try and determine this yourself by scraping the site URL's in question.  You'll probably want to rely on some 3rd party API which can check for you.

http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/

Check out that API, you can send it a URL and it will tell you what it thinks. This one is mainly checking for malware and phishing... not so much porn and spam. There are others that do the same thing, just search around on google.

Answer (score 2):

Manual moderation, perhaps. I can't think of any way to automate this other than using some sort of blacklist, but even then that is not always reliable as newer sites might not be on the list.

Additionally, you could try using cURL and downloading the index page and looking for certain keywords that would raise a red flag, and then perhaps hold those for manual validation.

I would suggest having a list of these keywords in array (porn, sex, etc). If the index page that you downloaded with cURL has any of those keywords, reject or flag for moderation.

This is not reliable nor is it the most optimized way of approving links.

Ultimately, you should have manual moderation regardless, but if you wish to automate it, this is a possible route for you to take.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a little monitoring system that will transfer this content created by user
to an approval queue that only administrators can access to approve the content that should
displayed at the site